# Yii2 Url rules with multiple string parameters

Tags: php, regex, yii2

I have problem to set url rules with two string parameters. I have the action "description" in controller "Article" like this:

```
public function actionDescription($cat, $subcat){ ... }
```

Then i set the url rules using different methods like below:

```
'Article/description/<cat:\S+>/<subcat:\S+>' => 'article/description'
'Article/description/<cat:\S+>/<subcat>' => 'article/description'
'Article/description/<cat:\S+>/<subcat:.*?>' => 'article/description'
```

I still get this url (The second parameter is not matching with the rules):

```
http://test.com/article/description/category+of+article?subcat=subcategory+of+article
```

Instaed of

```
http://test.com/article/description/category+of+article/subcategory+of+article
```

I call the url like this:

```
<?=  Html::a( Html::encode($subcategory->scName), ['article/description', 
                       'cat' =>$categoryModel->ccCategory, 
                       'subcat' =>$subcategory->scName], 
                        ['class' => 'subcat_link'])         
?>
```

Comment: How are creating that URL? Please show me full call.

Comment: @Bizley I have edited the question

Comment: Weird, the first rule should work.

Comment: I really don't  know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this rule

```
'article/description/<cat:[\w\s]+>/<subcat:[\w\s]+>' => 'article/description'
```

with this example

```
echo Url::to(['/article/description', 'cat' => 'category', 'subcat' => 'subcategory']);
```